# Vue Js - Typography

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, path, font-face

I have this folder structure in my vue.js app

[image]

In my typography.scss I have this declaration

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Gilroy-Black";
    src: url(fonts/Gilroy-Black.otf);
}
```

And in my login.vue file I have this import

```
@import "../../../sass/typography.scss";
```

But I get this error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './fonts/Gilroy-Black.otf' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\resources\js\pages\auth'
```

I would really appreciate a solution for this one,
Thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the answers to this GitHub issue could help you :
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5213

Angular users seems to experience a similar problem to yours.

Comment: That actually works! I've changed my .scss file into .css and that was basically all. Thank you a lot! :)